# How can I install Sun JDK on a Debian based system?

Tags: debian, java, jdk

I can't find any `.deb` packages for Sun's Java Development Kit. How can I install it on my Debian machine without causing conflicts with the already installed `openjdk` packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a Debian package from the Oracle tarball using the `make-jpkg` command from the `java-package` package. Here is an example:

```
make-jpkg jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

You can then install the resulting `.deb` file with `dpkg -i`:

```
sudo dpkg -i oracle-java7-jdk_7u45_amd64.deb
```

Finally, make this the default Java environment using `update-java-alternatives`:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s jdk-7-oracle-x64
```

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/Java/Sun

Comment: Damn, talk about reinventing the wheel. I'd read the wiki page and stopped at "Sun Java is no longer available in the repositories." :). Anyway, updated your answer with what I had to do to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Heh! Even AU doesn't have this method.

Answer (score 3):

Please use @jordanm's [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106963/22222). My approach works but his is easier and requires less manual intervention.

---

The latest version of Sun's JDK can be found on their website here:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

They don't offer `.deb` packages (only `.rpm`) so you will need to download the `.tar.gz` package for your architecture. In my case this was `jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz`. Once the package has been downloaded, extract it and move the expanded directory to `/usr/lib`:

```
tar xvzf jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz 
sudo mv jdk1.7.0_45/ /usr/lib/
```

You now need to tell Debian to use it. This is done through the nifty `update-alternatives` command. You need to run this once for each program in `/usr/lib/ jdk1.7.0_45/bin` to tell your system to use Sun's versions of these programs. You can combine the three in a little shell loop:

```
for i in /usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/*; do 
 i=$(basename $i); 
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/$i $i /usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/$i 1081; 
done
```

On my system, the installed `openjdk` executables had a priority of `1071` which is why I used `1081` in the above example. Your case might be different so once you have run the commands above, make sure the right executable has been chosen by running

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

The default (the one with the `*`) should be the JDK version you just installed. You can do the same for `javac` and `javaws`. You can use the same command to switch back and forth between available `java` executables.

Comment: I've never understood why Oracle/Sun do not distribute .deb files for Java. They have practically every other OS there would one more really break Oracle? To me this says it all as far as Oracle's opinion of Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: @slm yeah, it is weird. Is that a smug grin I see you hiding RH man?

Comment: Maybe just a smirk 8-). It's more b/c Oracle's Unbreakable Linux is why RPMs are available, and that a large customer base that use Java serve it on RHEL.